# Resetting the InputStream of a Java Socket after reaching EOS

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, java-io

I'm attempting to connect two separate applications via a TCP/IP socket. In this case neither of the applications is running as a "client" of the other, it would be easier to describe them as two separate servers who need to communicate with each other.

To receive the data I'm using the `InputStream.Read()` function and once it receives a value of `-1` it should stop processing. However, now the problem is that if another set of data comes along the `InputStream` is already at the End of Stream (`EOS`) and so all new data being sent is discarded or ignored. The only way I have found to fix this problem is that once the End of Stream has been reached I close the socket and reopen it which I think might be handled better some other way.

How can I reset the InputStream so that it is ready for the next set of data that may come along?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting EOS when reading from a TCP/IP Socket because the other end has closed the write side of its socket.  Once this happens, the TCP/IP protocol provides no way to "unclose" the connection.

If you don't want to have to open a new connection, you need an application protocol on top of the TCP/IP transport protocol that allows you to signify the end of each logical dataset ... without doing a close.

Comment: Figures it wouldn't be so simple. Well since I have no control of the other end as to it closing its write side I'll just have to go back to checking for EOS and then performing a close and open again. Thank you.